# About Windows file sharing

Tags: windows, file-sharing

Is it possible to run Windows file sharing exclusively over port 139, and close port 445 on the firewall between clients and server ?
If so, any settings need to be changed on clients and or server ?

Up till now our attempts have failed.

Thanks for any input !

Answer (score 1):

Port 139 is for [NetBIOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS),
so computers can see each other on the Windows network.

Port 445 is for [SMB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Message_Block)
(Server Message Block), which is where is actually done the
shared access to files, printers, serial ports and more.

So the answer is : No, port 445 is the one used for sharing.
Port 139 may be closed if you don't need NetBIOS (unlikely).

More info : [Difference between NetBIOS and SMB](https://superuser.com/questions/694469/difference-between-netbios-and-smb).